# Facebook API: Getting error in Insights API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying get reach data for all campaign from insight API call. I used https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/ACCOUNT_ID/insights?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&level=campaign&fields=reach&limit=50 .

But I am receiving error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#-2) Server timeout. Please wait and retry.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": -2
   }
}
```

I have all around 5000 campaigns.

Comment: If you decrease the limit, is there a point where it does work?

Comment: No. There is no effect of limit in this url. If I do not use limit then also it gets error.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide me with your ad account id? Also, please be aware of the limits as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group.

Comment: I could provide you account id but can't give you access token. Because it is my client's account. Let me know if it helps you to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes; so can you provide the ID, please?

Comment: Account id:  act_109044369289538

Comment: It seems that you exceed the limits described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign. Can you reduce the number or active adsets?